# La informacion en mi pdf se muestra muy pequeña. yii2

Tags: yii2

he renderizado vistas completas y de igual manera se ve pequeño la informacion por favor indicarme a que se debe esto. gracias de antemano

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
mi controllador

```
    public function actionReport() {

   $mpdf = new mPDF('A4');

    $mpdf->writeHTML('<h1>hola<h1>');
    $mpdf->Output('reporte.pdf','I');



     }
 }
```

Comment: Intenta cambiando los headers `Yii::$app->response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')` y `Yii::$app->response->headers->set('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary')` antes del output

Answer (score 0):

Este codigo me funciona con la **extension yii2-mpdf**

```
 use kartik\mpdf\Pdf;

 public function actionReport() {

    $content = "<h1> Hola mundo </h1>";
    $mpdf = new Pdf([ 'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
                      'content' => $content, ]);

    return $mpdf->render(); 
}
```

[Link documentación](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-mpdf)

Answer (score 0):

Intenta cambiando el tamaño de la fuente en los parámetros de la función mPDDF, en este caso te pongo un ejemplo con tamaño 20.

public function actionReport() {

$mpdf = new mPDF([
       'default_font_size' => 20
   ]);

```
$mpdf->writeHTML('<h1>hola<h1>');
$mpdf->Output('reporte.pdf','I');
```

}